# Views question with user reference

Tags: views, users

I have a content type courses with course name, instructor, coordinator and ta fields. Instructor and coordinator are of type user_reference.

My data looks like below

course   instructor    coordinator

101       joe           guo

102       joe           larry

103       guo           joe

My course view has filter criteria as below
content access: access and Contextual filter : author ID

When Joe logs in, the display looks like

Courses

101

102

103

I'm trying to figure out how to display only the courses joe is an instructor for. It should not show 103.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a contextual filter on your user reference field. It should be label like *Content: Instructor* (or whatever you named your instructor or coordinator field). For the **When the filter value is not in the URL** option, select *Provide the default value* and use the *User ID from logged in* user option.

Comment: Thanks you. This worked. How do I show all records 1/when administrator logs in and 2/user has a role 'chair'

Comment: Not sure. I've not had to use contextual filters for roles & role references. DA isn't a help forum, but a knowledge base. Mark this question as answered and ask that as a new question (after searching the site to see if it's been already asked).

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer to my question. I add this code php code
WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE -> Provide default value -> Type is PHP Code.

```
global $user;
if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
  return 'all';
}
else {
  return $user->uid;
}
```